# Create Django RESTful service for execute an algorithm

Tags: django, algorithm, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to implement a Django RESTful service where I can run an algorithm and get the result.

On the server I need to have a CSV file with the records for the algorithm. A service, let's say `/train` will allow me to train a Random Forest with the data in the CSV file, and finally another service `/predict` will receive the parameters and send me the result. The problem is that I have this running as a script on my computer and I don't know how to structure it for a web application.

I have already done RESTful APIs in Django but this problem is different I think.

1. I won't need models?
2. What about the serializers?

My idea is to send a GET request to `/predict` with the parameters needed for the Random Forest and return the algorithm result.

Any suggestions? Or a public repo with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

let say you have

`train_view` for '/train' with **POST** request.

`result_view` for `/predict`  with **GET** request

**Do you need models ?**

I think you need that since in request `/predict` you are going to apply logic on the data you have given in request `/train`, so create model.

**Do you need serializers**

Since you have model, you *can* write [modelserializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: At first, what I want to do is to train the model with the data in the CSV file **IN** the server (I need it right now...). I don't have to `POST` the CSV file. And then, with that model trained, I want to send a `GET` request and say "OK, with this new data, send me back the result of the algorithm". In this approach, I think I don't need models, but I don't know how to deal with the Serializers